# Making a div positioned absolute leave the boundary of it's parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

devs. I am experiencing a situation in which a div that is positioned absolute does not leave its parent boundary, instead, it is overflowing inside its parent boundary.

below is a sample of the code;

```
  <button className='unClear action-btn' onBlur={closeDrop} onClick={handleEdit}>
            action 
            {!dropDown ? <span className='icon small-icon'><AiFillCaretDown /></span> :<span className='icon small-icon'><AiFillCaretUp /></span> }
            
            {dropDown && <ul >
                <li>Update Invoice</li>
                <li>Edit Invoice</li>
                <li>Invoice Info</li>
                <li>Print Receipt</li>
                <li>Delete Invoice</li>
            </ul> }
        </button>)
```

And css

```
.action-btn{
   height: 2.5rem;
   width; 8rem;
   position: relative;
   ul{
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 2.75rem;
   li{
       height: 2.4rem;
       width: 100%;enter image description here
}
}
```

funny thing is I've used that code in my previous app but it's acting funny here
[image]

Comment: remove: top: 2.75rem;

Comment: It couldn't be considered "funny" tbh. It's how it's supposed to work. It positions based on its first positioned (position != static) parent:  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values

Answer (score 1):

As the absolutely positioned element is nested within a relatively positioned element, the position of the nested element is absolute **in relation to** the relatively positioned element.

You can try by removing the `position: relative` property, or using `position: inherit`